# How to restart single node hadoop cluster on ec2

Tags: hadoop, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ambari

I have installed a single node haodoop cluster on using Hortonworks/Ambari on Amazon's ec2 host.

Since I don't want this cluster running 24/7, I stop the instance when done. When I reboot the instance later, I get a new IP address and then ambari no longer is able to start the Hadoop related services.

Is there a way other than completely redeploying to reconfigure the cluster so the services will start?

It looks like the IP address lives in various xml files under /etc, in the postgres database table ambari, and possibly other places I haven't found yet.

I tried updating the xml files and postgres database with updated versions of the ip address, internal and external dns names as I could find them, but to no avail. I have not been able to restart the services.

The reason I am doing this is to possibly save the deployment time and data configuration on hdfs and other project specific setup each time I restart the host.

Any suggestions?

Thanks!

Comment: Without having any knowledge of Hortonworks/Ambari - You can associate your instance with an elastic IP. Elastic IP does not change and is associated with the instance even when it is down. Also, if you need to access the services internal to the AWS network, you can use the private IP. It also does not change.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Elastic IP can be used. Also, since you mentioned it being a single node cluster - you can use localhost or private IP.

If you use elastic IP, your UIs will always be on the same public IP. However, if you use private IP or localhost and do not associate your instance with an elastic IP you will have to look for public IP everytime you start the instance and then connect to the web UI using the IP.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the help, both Harman and TJ are correct. I haven't used an elastic IP because I might have more than one of these running and a time, and for now at least, I don't mind looking up the public ip address.

Harman's suggestion of using "`localhost`" as the fqdn when setting up ambari in the first place is a really good idea in retrospect. Unless I go through the whole setup again, that's water under the bridge for me, but I recommend this to others who might read this post.

In my case, I figured this out on my own before coming back to the page. The specific step I took was insanely simple after all, thanks to Occam's Razor.

I added the following line in /etc/hosts:
`<new internal IP> <old internal dns name>`
and then did 
`ambari-server restart`. from the command line. Then I am able to restart all services after logging into ambari.

Comment: Even better than my previous suggestion about /etc/hosts is to combine what I said, with Harman's suggestion about localhost:

I added the following line in /etc/hosts: 127.0.0.1 <old internal dns name>

Seems I don't need to do a restart on ambari-server either.

The benefit of this is that I don't have to edit /etc/hosts each time I acquire a new internal IP address when I fire up a new single node cluster.